# What happens to address's, values, and pointers after a fork()

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, memory-address, virtual-memory

I'm working on a question where I am to examine values and address before and after a `fork()` call in C. My approach was to display the variables values and address assuming to see a difference in the address after the `fork()`. Much to my surprise address's for said variables remained the same.

My questions is why are they the same? What happens if I change a variable in the child? Will it change in both parent and child? If not, how am I able to change the value in that address while the address is the same for both parent and child.

code(for reference):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
  int status;
  pid_t pid;

  int a = 123456;
  float b = 123.456;
  char c = 'Z';
  int *e;
  e=&a;

  //Retriving address's
  void *ap=&a, *bp=&b, *cp=&c, *ep=&e;

    printf("Parent Before Fork:\n");
    printf("Integer a: \tvalue = %d, \taddress = %p\n", a, ap);
    printf("Float b: \tvalue = %f, \taddress = %p\n", b, bp);
    printf("Char c: \tvalue = %c, \t\taddress = %p\n", c, cp);
    printf("Pointer e: \tvalue = %p, address = %p\n", e, ep);  

    pid = fork();

    if(pid > 0)
    {
      pid = wait(&status);
      printf("\nParent After Fork:\n");
      printf("Integer a: \tvalue = %d, \taddress = %p\n", a, ap);
      printf("Float b: \tvalue = %f, \taddress = %p\n", b, bp);
      printf("Char c: \tvalue = %c, \t\taddress = %p\n", c, cp);
      printf("Pointer e: \tvalue = %p, address = %p\n", e, ep);

      sleep(1);
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
      printf("\nChild After Fork:\n");
      printf("Integer a: \tvalue = %d, \taddress = %p\n", a, ap);
      printf("Float b: \tvalue = %f, \taddress = %p\n", b, bp);
      printf("Char c: \tvalue = %c, \t\taddress = %p\n", c, cp);
      printf("Pointer e: \tvalue = %p, address = %p\n", e, ep);
   }
   else
     printf("fork() did not work");

return 0; 
}
```

output(for refrence):

```
Parent Before Fork:
Integer a:  value = 123456,         address = 0x7fff8b8e378c
Float b:    value = 123.456001,     address = 0x7fff8b8e3790
Char c:     value = Z,              address = 0x7fff8b8e3787
Pointer e:  value = 0x7fff8b8e378c, address = 0x7fff8b8e3798

Child After Fork:
Integer a:  value = 123456,         address = 0x7fff8b8e378c
Float b:    value = 123.456001,     address = 0x7fff8b8e3790
Char c:     value = Z,              address = 0x7fff8b8e3787
Pointer e:  value = 0x7fff8b8e378c, address = 0x7fff8b8e3798

Parent After Fork:
Integer a:  value = 123456,         address = 0x7fff8b8e378c
Float b:    value = 123.456001,     address = 0x7fff8b8e3790
Char c:     value = Z,              address = 0x7fff8b8e3787
Pointer e:  value = 0x7fff8b8e378c, address = 0x7fff8b8e3798
```

Comment: How could they possibly change? Think about it. There's no way that could possibly work.

Comment: Upon further research, what I was expecting was a physical memory address, while what was displayed is the virtual memory address. It is not possible to have two variables in the same physical address but it is possible to have two virtual memory address's being referred from one virtual memory address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child process has a copy of the parent address space. In modern systems addresses are virtualized, so that any particular pointer address can map in one process to a different *physical address* than it does in another process.

> What happens if I change a variable in the child? Will it change in both parent and child?

The child has its own copy of the variable, so changing a variable in the child will not affect the value of the variable in the parent.

> If not, how am I able to change the value in that address while the addres is the same for both parent and child.

This is due to the same address in both processes mapping to different physical addresses.

Comment: Is it possible to display the physical memory address's?

Comment: @AndrewRicci generally not - and generally, you don't/shouldn't care what physical address your code/data resides at, as it really makes no difference. Furthermore the address may change as the program runs - memory can be paged in and out.

Comment: And likely right after the `fork`, they will have the same physical address. There's no need to make a copy until one program or the other modifies the contents. (So the physical address will change on a write!)

Comment: @AndrewRicci, adding to the comment issued by davmac, physical addresses can even change while the program is running, or even not exist at all.  Virtual memory can be swapped out to disk and then the actual virtual address, when referenced, just hits a page fault, the kernel swaps it in (at a mostly sure different physical address) and you get it again.

Answer (score 2):

The address is the same, but doesn't refer to the same memory. Each process has its own address space. This is accomplished on modern systems by virtual memory - on older systems it would be accomplished by segment-base addressing or simply swapping (unloading one process and loading the other one in the same region of memory).

Comment: Note that fork() is usually implemented using copy-on-write pages, that is, the addresses will refer to the *same* memory as long as there are no writes to that page.

Comment: It's not _conceptually_ the same memory, though. Copy on write is an implementation detail.