# Multiprocessing doesn't recreate object

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have created a little code snippet (the original code is much larger) that calls a function which creates an object, but within a pool of processes:

```
import multiprocessing


class TestClass(object):
    pass


def func():
    obj = TestClass()
    cpname = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print "{0}, Address: {1}".format(cpname, str(obj))


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
results = [pool.apply_async(func) for _ in range(2)]

for res in results:
    res.get()

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
PoolWorker-1, Address: <__main__.TestClass object at 0x7f05d3fdad50>
PoolWorker-2, Address: <__main__.TestClass object at 0x7f05d3fdad50>
```

1. What I don't understand is, why the objects have the same address, even though the are in separate processes?
2. How can I make sure that every process creates its own object?

Thank you very much fir your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects are different, different processes use different [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and the same address in different processes points to the different memory region.

If you change your example little bit you'll see that returned objects are different:

```
import multiprocessing

class TestClass(object):
    pass

def func():
    obj = TestClass()
    cpname = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print "{0}, Address: {1}".format(cpname, str(obj))
    return obj

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
results = [pool.apply_async(func) for _ in range(2)]

results = [res.get() for res in results]

pool.close()
pool.join()

print results
```

Answer (score 3):

When you `fork()` for multiprocessing, it duplicates your process. The memory allocator and all addresses in the parent process will be copied into the child process. As a result, the next allocation will be very likely to have the same address.

You can verify that they are in fact separate objects like so:

```
import time

def func():
    obj = TestClass()
    obj.name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print obj.name, str(obj)
    time.sleep(1)
    print obj.name, str(obj)
```

Comment: I have run your code. The result puzzles me a bit, as addresses are still the same (or is that to be expected):

` PoolWorker-1 <__main__.TestClass object at 0x7ffecd3c8d90>
PoolWorker-2 <__main__.TestClass object at 0x7ffecd3c8d90>
PoolWorker-1 <__main__.TestClass object at 0x7ffecd3c8d90>
PoolWorker-2 <__main__.TestClass object at 0x7ffecd3c8d90> `

Comment: The addresses are expected to be the same due to virtual addressing. When you clone a program in place for multiprocessing, the virtual addresses don't change but the underlying physical memory does.

Answer (score 1):

Seems likely you're using a Linux-ish system, where new process are created via `fork()`.  In that case, you should *expect* a great deal of overlap between addresses.  That doesn't mean your `obj` instances occupy the same physical memory - just that they share the same *virtual* (process-local) addresses.

More here:

[What happens to address's, values, and pointers after a fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021639/what-happens-to-addresss-values-and-pointers-after-a-fork)